# Is getPreferredPreviewSizeForVideo() a good way go get the right preview size?

Tags: java, android, camera, preview

I'm building a part of an android app, that displays a camera preview. I'd like to set the correct (best) preview size possible for the current device.

To accomplish this, I used the following code:

```
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int format, int w, int h) {
    Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
    List<Size> sizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();

    // the list seems to be in that order, that the best quality is the first element
    parameters.setPreviewSize(sizes.get(0).width, sizes.get(0).height);

    camera.setParameters(parameters);
    camera.startPreview();
}
```

Now my question is, if the following method would be better to get the best preview quality for any device?

```
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int format, int w, int h) {
    Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();

    Size preferredSize = parameters.getPreferredPreviewSizeForVideo();
    parameters.setPreviewSize(preferredSize.width, preferredSize.height);

    camera.setParameters(parameters);
    camera.startPreview();
}
```

Currently I have just one device (Nexus 4) and on this one both methods result in the same. But I'm wondering, which method you would suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs for `getPreferredPreviewSizeForVideo()`:

> Camcorder applications should set the preview size to a value that is not larger than the preferred preview size. In other words, the product of the width and height of the preview size should not be larger than that of the preferred preview size.

So, since it basically says the preview should not be bigger than the preferred size, this method *should* return the largest preview size available.

I'd also recommend using that method, because the list returned by `getSupportedPreviewSizes()` is not *guaranteed* to be in order. I haven't seen one out of order yet, but that doesn't mean that every device will honor it.

Comment: On a Galaxy Nexus (4.2.2) the method getSupportedPreviewSizes() returns null. So I have to use both approaches to set the best preview size. Would you agree to that?

Comment: Sure, if one gives a null, try the other. Odd about the null, though. My gNex doesn't do that.

Comment: on htc one x using getPreferredPreviewSizeForVideo() does not look very nice. I live what camera startPreview sets itself.

Comment: It's odd about `getSupportedPreviewSizes` returning `null` because according to the documentation it states that "This method will always return a list with at least one element." http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedPreviewSizes()

Comment: @MaxWorg Internally it calls [`splitSize()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.2_r1/android/hardware/Camera.java#Camera.Parameters.splitSize%28java.lang.String%29) and just returns it the way it comes with [no further checks](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.2_r1/android/hardware/Camera.java#Camera.Parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes%28%29). `splitSize()` could easily return null from the look of it, so maybe somebody should tell them about this.

Comment: Yeah maybe that is an issue that should be reported.  It seems that `getPreferredPreviewSizeForVideo()` is a good way to go since it will also take the aspect ratio into consideration. Are there any downsides to using this method to set picturePreviewSize? Besides mAx's answers that it returns a very small preview size the majority of the time it should return a usable result.

Comment: @MaxWorg No major downsides that I know of, but I must admit that I haven't played with the camera much since Jelly Bean.

Answer (score 3):

I can not really recommend using this method. On the Galaxy S4 this method returns a preferred video preview size of 176x144. Seems like the developers accidentally returned the smallest instead of the largest size here... if you use this as preview it looks ugly and even destroys the recorded video.

Comment: Take a look at [my answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18154044/1977828) where I showed the algorithm I ended up using.

Comment: We ran into the same issue and finally did a manual selection by code. e.g. Xperia SP, Samsung SII, S3 and Wildfire S have different sorting criteria

Comment: I have also found the preferred video preview size to be 176x144 on the Galaxy S4 Mini (GT-I9195)