# S4 picture taken with custom camera is damage

Tags: android, android-camera

I have this weird problem with my custom camera in the samsung S4. I all other devices I have tested it works, even on S4 mini.

The pictures taken looks like this:

[image]

There is these white stripes, what could these be?

The code does not do nothing weird, I think...

```
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera myCamera) {
        File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
        if (pictureFile == null) {
            return;
        }

        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            fos.write(data);
            fos.close();

            resizeImage(pictureFile.getPath());

            Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
            returnIntent.putExtra("path", pictureFile.getPath());
            setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
            finish();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            //stuff
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //stuff
        }
    }
```

This is the resize, maybe has something to do:

```
private void resizeImage(String picturePath) {
    try {

        Bitmap bitmapIn = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);

        Float w = (float) bitmapIn.getWidth();
        Float h = (float) bitmapIn.getHeight();

        Float aspect = w / h;

        if ((w * h) > 120000) {

            Bitmap bitmapOut;

            int neww = 400;

            if (w < h) {
                neww = 300;
            }

            Float newh = (h * neww) / w;

            bitmapOut = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapIn, neww,
                    newh.intValue(), false);

            File file = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
            FileOutputStream fOut;

            fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmapOut.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 60, fOut);
            fOut.flush();
            fOut.close();
            bitmapOut.recycle();
        } else {

        }

        bitmapIn.recycle();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        //stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using a lower resolution. I ran into that behavior with my CWAC-Camera library, and my temporary conclusion is that some devices lie about their maximum resolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can solve this problem, using optimal picture size according to device.

[What is the best camera parameters for android camera opened in surface view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153650/what-is-the-best-camera-parameters-for-android-camera-opened-in-surface-view)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a solution for you...

I had the same problem and an interesting situation occurred in the Samsung S4!

The problem appear when the image size was much smaller than the size of the preview. For example: Preview Size: 1920 x 1080 and 640 x 480 Picture Size. So... the device set the Max resolution for picture and I don't know why...

To solve this problem, you must be combine both sizes: Preview Size and Picture Size. Its ok for me. With 2 sizes combined, the white stripes not appear! :-)